# UITableView internal inconsistency

Tags: swift, uitableview

im updating a tableview cell on some condition in the following way:

```
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
```

im getting crashes on the firebase crashlytics as below:

```
UITableView internal inconsistency: encountered out of bounds global row index while preparing batch updates (oldRow=1, oldGlobalRowCount=1)
```

if anyone has an idea what the case could be, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your table view `datasource` seems like not updating before it attempts to redraw. Try placing your code between `beginUpdated` and `endUpdates`

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: didnt fix the issue